How to raise a vector to powers contained in a vector, change the list into a product, and do this for all the lines of a matrix, efficiently?
I want to raise the first vector var to the powers in a second vector, and then multiply the list, when the second vector runs over all lines of a matrix expo.
I wrote a pure function expM.  For example,  with
var = Array[x, 5]; expo = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
{0, 1, 0,  0, 1}};expM = Exp@Total@Log@Power[#1, #2] &; expM[var, #] & /@ expo

the output is $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3 x_4,x_2 x_5\right\}$
Can you recommend a better way, maybe a Mathematica command, to do that more simply?

Use Inner
Inner[Power, var, #, Times] & /@ expo

(* {x[1],x[2],x[3] x[4],x[2] x[5]} *)


This feels like I was just following the directions in the OP:
Times @@ (var^#) & /@ expo


Obfuscatory variant at one level down: (var^Array[Slot, Length@var] // Apply@Times // Map@*Apply@*Function)@expo

Here is another Inner strategy:
Inner[OperatorApplied[Power], expo, var, Times]


expo . Log@var // Exp


(* {x[1],x[2],x[3] x[4],x[2] x[5]} *)

